# what if there is no repeat_interval in dbms_scheduler.create_job

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jobs

I have created a Job using this.

```
BEGIN 
   dbms_scheduler.create_job ( 
    job_name => 'test_JOB', 
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
    JOB_ACTION => 'UP_TRYNR;', 
    start_date =>sysdate, 
    enabled => true, 
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1'
   ); 
END;
```

If I create the job without specifying `repeat_interval` what will happen? i.e.

```
BEGIN 
   dbms_scheduler.create_job ( 
    job_name => 'test_JOB', 
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
    JOB_ACTION => 'UP_TRYNR;', 
    start_date =>sysdate, 
    enabled => true, 
   ); 
END;
```

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The job will run only once (provided `start_date` is in future)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#i1013037

Comment: ["If no value for repeat_interval is specified, the job runs only once at the specified start date."](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN10040).

Comment: Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 4):

The `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package includes functionality that can be used to set up and manage the timetabling and execution of tasks that need to be run according to a – repeating or non-repeating – schedule.
`DBMS_SCHEDULER` breaks the process of scheduling a task into 3 parts:

1. Create a schedule
2. Identify a ‘program’ – by which they mean the procedure you wish to
   run
3. Create a ‘job’ – by which they mean chain a program to a schedule.

As name suggests `Repeat_interval`,describes the frequency when the programs needs to be executed. This is a bit like the cron syntax in UNix.

If you create it without any `Repeat_interval`,it would execute only `once` at the specified `startdate` and then remain `dormant`.